# What does this Gtk error mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

```
**

Gtk:ERROR:/build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.22.0/gtk/gtktoolbar.c:2248:logical_to_physical: assertion failed: (logical == 0)
Aborted
```

This is happening when I run code analogous to:

```
if condition:
    self.insert(self.toolbutton, 0)
```

where self is an instance of a subclass of gtk.Toolbar. The error only occurs when condition is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the cause of the problem. There was a number of similar statements. The problem was due to hard coding the index. Using this form:

```
if condition:
    self.insert(self.toolbutton, self.insert(self.toolbutton, self._n)
    self._n += 1
```

fixes it. (self._n is originally 0).

Answer (score 0):

Is there an **else**, or **elif** clause, or is it just that single **if** clause that, when not satisfied, causes it to bomb out?